# \hline does not produce anything

Tags: tables, luatex

I am trying to create a simple table with visible lines and columns separators (horizontal and vertical lines).

The LaTeX code seems straightforward. To draw horizontal lines, you should insert the command "\hline". That's what I do. However, the lines are not visible. Please note that there are no warnings during the execution of LuaLatex (see the annexe for the versions).

The LaTeX code is very simple :

```
\documentclass{cv}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
       \hline
       PHP5/7   & Expert & 20 ans & 100\% \\
       \hline
       PHP5/7   & Expert & 20 ans & 100\% \\
   \end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

I also give you the code for the class "cv" : see the annexe.

I spent a day searching on the Internet... but I can't find any reason why the lines are not visible.

Any idea ?

Best regards,

Denis

## ANNEXE

#### Versions

- I use TexLive version **6.2.1** (tex -x) on **Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS**.
- I use LuaLatex (version **beta-0.80.0**) to produce the PDF document.

#### The class "cv"

% This file contains LaTeX configuration for all CV.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{cv}[1995/10/30 Standard LaTeX minimal class]

% [geometry] This package provides a flexible and easy interface to page dimensions.
\usepackage[a4paper,
            % We set the dimensions of the left and right margins.
            left=1cm,
            right=1cm,
            % We set the dimensions of the top and bottom margins.
            top=2cm,
            bottom=2cm]{geometry}

% We (must) redefine the font size named "normalsize" (this is mandatory).
% Please note that LaTeX defines other names for font sizes (for example: tiny, small...).
% See https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles#Reference_guide
% WARNING: Make sure to redefine the command "\normalsize" before loading the package "fontspec".
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

% This package allows users of LuaTeX to load OpenType fonts in a LaTeX document.
% Find the names of all fonts under Ubuntu:
% find /usr/share/texmf/fonts/ -name "*.otf" | xargs -n1 fc-scan --format "%{fullname}\n" | sed 's/,.\+$//'
% See https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec
% WARNING: This package needs the font size named "normalsize" to be defined!
\usepackage{fontspec}

% This package allows the use of formatting features that are required to draw tables.
\usepackage{array}
```

#### The command I use to generate the PDF

This is a Makefile:

```
# This document illustrates the use of the "make" tool to produce PDF files from LaTeX sources.
# 
#      Generate the PDF file:                     make 
#      Clean all the temporary files:             make clean
#      Clean everything (including the PDF file): make clear

LATEX_EXE     = /usr/bin/lualatex
LATEX_OPTIONS = -halt-on-error -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode --output-format=pdf
PDF_VIEWER    = xdg-open

perso.pdf: perso.tex cv.cls
        ${LATEX_EXE} ${LATEX_OPTIONS} $< && echo "SUCCESS" && ${PDF_VIEWER} $@

all: perso.pdf

clean:
        rm -f *.log *.out *.aux

clear: clean
        rm -f *.pdf
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I can reproduce your problem.

Comment: why is your class (which uses fontspec) claiming to be written in 1995 and be the standard latex minimal class? `\ProvidesClass{cv}[1995/10/30 Standard LaTeX minimal class]` ?

Answer (score 4):

The class is too scanty and doesn't set very important parameters, among which `\arrayrulewidth` and `\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass{cv}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
       \hline
       PHP5/7   & Expert & 20 ans & 100\% \\
       \hline
       PHP5/7   & Expert & 20 ans & 100\% \\
   \end{tabular}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Usually classes are built upon another one, such as `article`, not upon `minimal` (this class is only for experiments, not for producing actual documents, see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)).

If I add `\LoadClass{article}` just after the `\ProvidesClass` line, the output of your unmodified example is

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I could have lost a lot of time trying to find the answer. Please note that, coming from the software industry, I expected LaTeX to launch an error if some dependencies were missing.